# Trying to remember a sci-fi/fantasy cartoon

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification

I believe from the early 90's involving either brothers or best friends who were involved in toxic accident. I know what your thinking toxic crusaders but I don't believe that's it. One of the boys had slime in his stomach or something like that, I remember him and his crew fighting bad guys. I wanna say it came out around the same time as biker mice from Mars.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).